# Python - fading led colors depending on temperature

Tags: python

I am using a raspberry pi, tip120 transistors, and python 2.7 to control an led strip, everything is working correctly except for fading between colors.  I am trying to fade from one color to another depending on a temperature reading, currently I can set the color of the led, but it wont fade.  Here is my code so far, I'm pretty new to python so any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
        if (x <= 77):
        ledred=100
        ledgreen=100
        ledblue=100
    elif (x > 78) and (x < 80):
            for i in range(ledred,-1,-1):
                ledred=i
            for j in range(ledgreen,-1,-1):
                ledgreen=j
            for k in range(ledblue,100,1):
                ledblue=k
    elif (x > 80) and (x < 100):
            for i in range(ledred,-1,-1):
                ledred=i
            for j in range(ledgreen,100,1):
                ledgreen=j
            for k in range(ledblue,-1,-1):
                ledblue=k
    elif (x > 100) and (x < 110):
            cycle=100
            for i in range(ledred,100,1):
                ledred=i
            for j in range(ledgreen,100,1):
                ledgreen=j
            for k in range(ledblue,-1,-1):
                ledblue=k
    else (x > 110):
            for i in range(ledred,100,1):
                ledred=i
            for j in range(ledgreen,-1,-1):
                ledgreen=j
            for k in range(ledblue,-1,-1):
                ledblue=k
    red.ChangeDutyCycle(ledred)
    green.ChangeDutyCycle(ledgreen)
    blue.ChangeDutyCycle(ledblue)
```

Comment: Your `elif` statements could be rewritten as `if 80 > x > 78:` for example. Also I suggest correcting the indentation on your first line so as not to confuse. https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in

Comment: Why all the `for` loops? They'll execute so quickly that you won't see the transition.

Comment: I was using a sample from the rpi.gpio library docs `for i in range(0,101): 
            white.ChangeDutyCycle(i)  
            red.ChangeDutyCycle(100 - i)  
            sleep(pause_time)  
        for i in range(100,-1,-1):      # from 100 to zero in steps of -1  
            white.ChangeDutyCycle(i)  
            red.ChangeDutyCycle(100 - i)  
            sleep(pause_time)  `

I'm unsure of how to initiate the new transition when the temperature changes (ex: the temperature(x) > 110 decrease the duty cycle for blue and green, and increase the duty cycle of red)

Comment: @MarkRansom also they only use the final value of `ledred`, the loops don't affect the LED, only the expression `red.ChangeDutyCycle(ledred)`. Same for other LEDs.

Comment: @MarkRansom also that's only a snippet of the code, there at the end it sleeps for 0.02 seconds before running the loop again.  What I want the loop to do is keep the last loops value for ledred, ledgreen, and ledblue, and then use range to either adjust them up or down in increments of 1 based on what the temperature is for the next loop.

Comment: Would using something like this: `x = 1
while True:
    x = x+1` in place of range help me accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after rewriting it trying several different methods, the following code does pretty much what I want.  It checks the temperature (x), then based on the temperature will initialize a duty cycle change in each of the led color channels (red, green, blue respectively).  Each cycle of the loop adjusts the duty cycle up or down by 7, and the values for each color are capped and 0 and 100.  The transition can be made more dramatic or less dramatic by adjusting the number added to w, y, and z.  I have added an object (fan1) and just finished etching my first circuit board.  I now have a fully functional raspberry pi 7-fan fan controller with led temperature indication.  This will be added to my custom case build.  I appreciate the the help that was offered.  Thanks and here is the final working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7  
# script by Eric Johnsten utilizing info from:
#http://RasPi.tv/2013/how-to-use-soft-pwm-in-rpi-gpio-pt-2-led-dimming-and-motor-speed-control
#https://github.com/SimplyAutomationized/raspberrypi/tree/master/pidfanpi

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO # always needed with RPi.GPIO  
import testtemp 
import os
from time import sleep  # pull in the sleep function from time module  

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  #choose BCM or BOARD numbering schemes. 

GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)  #set GPIO 17 as output for fan1  
#GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT) #set GPIO 18 as output for fan2  
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.OUT)  #Red Channel
GPIO.setup(19, GPIO.OUT)  #Green Channel
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT)  #Blue Channel

fan1 = GPIO.PWM(17, 100)    #object fan1 for PWM on port 17 at 100 Hertz  
#fan2 = GPIO.PWM(18, 100)   #object fan2 for PWM on port 18 at 100 Hertz  
blue = GPIO.PWM(26, 100)    #object for red channel 100 Hertz
red = GPIO.PWM(19, 100)     #object for green channel 100 Hertz
green = GPIO.PWM(13, 100)   #object for blue channel 100 Hertz

fan1.start(0)
#fan2.start(0)
red.start(50)
green.start(50)
blue.start(50)

w=100
y=100
z=100
f=0

try:
    while True:
        #sleep(.02)
        os.system('clear')
    #get temperature from sensor and determine pwm fan speed
    x = testtemp.read_temp()
    print x
    if (x <= 77):
        w=w+7
        y=y+7
        z=z+7
        if (w > 100):
            w=100
        if (y > 100):
            y=100
        if  (z > 100):
            z=100
        if (w < 0):
            w=0
        if (y < 0):
            y=0
        if (z < 0):
            z=0
        red.ChangeDutyCycle(w)
        green.ChangeDutyCycle(y)
        blue.ChangeDutyCycle(z)
        f=0
    elif (x > 78) and (x < 80):
        w=w-7
        y=y-7
        z=z+7
        f=60
        if (w > 100):
            w=100
        if (y > 100):
            y=100
        if  (z > 100):
            z=100
        if (w < 0):
            w=0
        if (y < 0):
            y=0
        if (z < 0):
            z=0
        red.ChangeDutyCycle(w)
        green.ChangeDutyCycle(y)
        blue.ChangeDutyCycle(z)
        fan1.ChangeDutyCycle(60)
    elif (x > 80) and (x < 100):
        w=w-7
        y=y+7
        z=z-7
        f=70
        if (w > 100):
            w=100
        if (y > 100):
            y=100
        if  (z > 100):
            z=100
        if (w < 0):
            w=0
        if (y < 0):
            y=0
        if (z < 0):
            z=0
        red.ChangeDutyCycle(w)
        green.ChangeDutyCycle(y)
        blue.ChangeDutyCycle(z)
        fan1.ChangeDutyCycle(70)
    elif (x > 100) and (x < 110):
        w=w+7
        y=y+7
        z=z-7
        f=85
        if (w > 100):
            w=100
        if (y > 100):
            y=100
        if  (z > 100):
            z=100
        if (w < 0):
            w=0
        if (y < 0):
            y=0
        if (z < 0):
            z=0
        red.ChangeDutyCycle(w)
        green.ChangeDutyCycle(y)
        blue.ChangeDutyCycle(z)
        fan1.ChangeDutyCycle(85)
    elif (x > 110):
        w=w+7
        y=y-7
        z=z-7
        f=100
        if (w > 100):
            w=100
        if (y > 100):
            y=100
        if  (z > 100):
            z=100
        if (w < 0):
            w=0
        if (y < 0):
            y=0
        if (z < 0):
            z=0
        red.ChangeDutyCycle(w)
        green.ChangeDutyCycle(y)
        blue.ChangeDutyCycle(z)
        fan1.ChangeDutyCycle(100)
    print 'Setpoint: 77.0F \nTemp: '+str(testtemp.read_temp())+' \nFan Speed: ',str(f)+'%'
    print w
    print y
    print z
    sleep(0.02)
except KeyboardInterrupt:  
fan1.stop()             # stop Fan 1 PWM output  
#fan2.stop()            # stop Fan 2 PWM output 
red.stop()              # stop red leds
green.stop()            # stop green leds
blue.stop()             # stop blue leds
GPIO.cleanup()          # clean up GPIO on CTRL+C exit  
pass
```